# Glyph shows over pull down menu

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am updating an Angular app to use Bootstrap 3 glyphicons instead of some images, and have run into the following difficulty:

I have this glyph in a view that's in my content section:

```
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
```

and this one in a pull-down menu:

```
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>
```

It seems that when I pull down the menu, the "-play" glyph is not hidden and still shows through it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is without seeing more of your code, but you could add some quick jQuery to show/hide the appropriate icon on click.

```
$('.the-dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('i.glyphicon-play').hide();
});
```